# How to fetch results one by one in Doctrine 1.2?

Tags: php, doctrine, dql, doctrine-1.2

How can I make something similar to classic PHP PDO

```
while ($obj = $stmt->fetch()) {...}
```

in Doctrine 1.2.

I've tried

```
while ($obj = $query->fetchOne()) {...}
```

but it returns always only the first object found.

Is there any way I could implement this behaviour?

Doesn't really matter my query. It's a plain simple one (note that I am in the *Table class of the model)

```
$query = $this->createQuery('a');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
while ($obj = $query->execute()) {...}
```

And if you want to fetch an array instead of objects:

```
while ($obj = $query->execute(array(), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY)) {...}
```

Comment: I am trying now but I think that $query->execute() returns all the collection so no use for the while

Comment: This is not working as I wished. Because the Doctrine_Collection uses too much memory. I wanted to do as clasic PDO to work like a buffer between logic and sql. Retrieve one object work with it and dispose of. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You still can check the [doc](http://doctrine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/en/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#select-queries).

Comment: offtopic - don't know if this is ok to ask. but I see you have some experience with symfony. do you know any deploy tool that is ok and easy to use with symfony and git/svn?

Comment: Wow.. looks great at first look. Works with both 1 and 2 sf. Just one more questions because this is my 1st time I use deploing tool. In capifony when I deploy automatically it runs the migrations?

Comment: I don't know (I didn't use it yet). But it seems that you just have to define [new action (in french)](http://dev.sans-bouger.fr/article?ref=symfony&nom=installer-capifony-pour-symfony-1-4).

Answer (score 1):

While working on a migration command in symfony2 I discovered that `$query->executes();` fetches the complete result set into RAM before returning it.

This is not a problem with a small amount of data, but with bigger results your process might run OutOfMemory.

To solve the problem you can iterate through the results "one by one" with this statement:

```
$query->iterate();
```

I thing its similare to this PDO statement: `while ($obj = $stmt->fetch()) {...}`

A more complete example might look like this:

```
$em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine');
$iterator = $em->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Entity')
               ->createQueryBuilder('e')
               ->getQuery()->iterate();

foreach($iterator as $item){
   $item = $item[0];

   // Your logic here:
   $item->getId();
   ....       
}
```

Found this in the **[doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/batch-processing.html#iterating-results).**

Comment: This is for Doctrine 2, OP asked for Doctrine 1.

Comment: Ups! Yes you´re right, I stumbled over this answer while googling for a solution in doctrine(2).

Answer (score 0):

If you got the connection, do it like this:

```
$stmt = $conn->query($queryString);
while ($obj = $stmt->fetch()) {...}
```

With `fetchOne()` you will only get one entry at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use the hydrate mode `Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ON_DEMAND`

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
                ->select('...')
                ->from('...');

// Returns instance of Doctrine_Collection_OnDemand
$result = $q->execute(array(), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ON_DEMAND);
foreach ($result as $obj)
{
    // do something with your object
}
```

More information : [Data Hydrators — Doctrine 1.2.4 documentation](http://doctrine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/en/manual/data-hydrators.html)